# What's the halachik classification as to why Dolphins aren't kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, animals, fish, non-kosher-species

What's the **halachik classification** as to why Dolphins aren't kosher?

Is it because:

**Dolphins are like a fish**

they live in the ocean and thus the Torah considers them a fish and they don't have fins and scales?

**OR**

**Dolphins are like other mammals**

they're a mammal and like the other kosher mammals they don't have split hooves and chew their cud?

**Practical difference:** (H/T [Heshy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11532/heshy))

What warning would witnesses have to give to someone who's about to eat Dolphin;
"don't eat that non-kosher fish!" or "don't eat that non-kosher animal!"

Comment: Bats are mammals but their feet don't matter. What do you mean by "like other mammals"?

Comment: @DoubleAA that have the traits of mammals- warmblooded, don't lay eggs, etc https://www.thoughtco.com/the-main-mammal-characteristics-4086144

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the answer to the question is found in the one you linked it to, thanks (Aruch Hashulchan)

Comment: Bats have those traits but their feet don't matter.

Comment: @DoubleAA right can apply the same question about dolphins to bats- are like birds OR are like other mammals

Comment: @DoubleAA before you ask, does everyone 100% agree *atalef* means a bat?

Comment: Either the Atalef is a bat (or the Tinshamet is a bat) or the Atalef is a platypus. Those are pretty much your options.

Comment: @DoubleAA and of course neither are kosher. Do you think the "mammal"/ biology labels are more modern era constructs that the Torah didn't really care about in determining what is/isn't kosher?